# Extract row from pandas dateframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as the image below. I want to extract the rows of data frame which are having year and month as '1395/01'. I used the code below, but I know it is not correct because we can use string slice on a series of strings. Can anyone show me a way without using nested for loops?

```
df[df['Date'][:7] == '1395/01']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use `str.match` here:

```py
df[df['Date'].str.match(r'^1395/01')]
```

But in general it is usually preferable to store dates as `datetime` and not text.  Also, the year 1395 seems dubious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loc and startswith to filter your dataframe.

**Sample:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1395/01/01', '1395/02/01', '1395/01/01', '1395/05/01']})
print(df)

          Date
0   1395/01/01
1   1395/02/01
2   1395/01/01
3   1395/05/01
```

**Solution:**

```
print(df.loc[df['Date'].str.startswith('1395/01'), :])

          Date
0   1395/01/01
2   1395/01/01
```

If you would like to extract year and month for all rows, you can use str.slice:

```
df['Extracted Date'] = df['Date'].str.slice(0, 7)
print(df)

          Date  Extracted Date
0   1395/01/01         1395/01
1   1395/02/01         1395/02
2   1395/01/01         1395/01
3   1395/05/01         1395/05
```